# How to exclude language code from NFC tag message

Tags: java, android, nfc, message, ndef

I'm creating a simple Android App to write to an NFC tag. So far it works but it seems to be adding the language code on to the beginning of the message. So how do I get it to not be there when I read the message on the tag?
I'm using a separate app to read it.

```
private void formatTag(Tag tag, NdefMessage ndefMessage) {
    try {
        NdefFormatable ndefFormatable = NdefFormatable.get(tag);
        if(ndefFormatable == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Tag is not ndef formatable!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        ndefFormatable.connect();
        ndefFormatable.format(ndefMessage);
        ndefFormatable.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Tag written!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("formatTag", e.getMessage());
    }
}
private void writeNdefMessage(Tag tag, NdefMessage ndefMessage) {
    try {
        if (tag == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Tag object cannot be null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
        if(ndef == null) {
            formatTag(tag, ndefMessage);
        } else {
            ndef.connect();
            if(!ndef.isWritable()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Tag is not writable!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ndef.close();
                return;
            }
            ndef.writeNdefMessage(ndefMessage);
            ndef.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Tag written!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("writeNdefMessage", e.getMessage());
    }
}

private NdefMessage createNdefMessage(String content)  {
    NdefRecord ndefRecord = NdefRecord.createTextRecord("en", content);
    NdefMessage ndefMessage = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[]{ndefRecord});
    return ndefMessage;
}
```

The `en` in this code is what is being added to my message

Comment: Do you read the NDEF message with your own app? How do you read the record there?

Comment: Hi! have you resolved the issue?